# How to check the string whether it was arabic language or not in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

How can I check if the string is arabic or not based one that I have to update the my language ID column as English or Arabic

```
 IF(PATINDEX('%[^أ-ي]%', RTRIM(@STRING))=0)
        BEGIN
              SET @RETURNVALUE='A'
        END
 ELSE IF(PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z]%', RTRIM(@STRING))=0)
        BEGIN
              SET @RETURNVALUE='E'
        END
```

If suppose name starts with S and follows arabic name it was throwing null

EX: `set @STRING= N'العربيةs'`

kindly help to sort out this issue ?

Answer (score 5):

The IF statement you use effectively says:

> If the string does not contain a non-arabic character, set result to
>   'A'
>
> Otherwise, if the string does not contain a non-latin character,
>   set result to 'E'

If you have strings containing both scripts, arabic AND latin, the result value is not set.

Remove the negation in the regex, like this:

```
declare @string nvarchar(50), @returnvalue varchar (50)

set @string = N'العربيةs'
set @returnvalue = ''

IF(PATINDEX(N'%[أ-ي]%', RTRIM(@string ))>0)
    BEGIN
      SET @returnvalue= @returnvalue + 'A'
    END
IF(PATINDEX(N'%[A-Za-z]%', RTRIM(@string ))>0)
    BEGIN
      SET @returnvalue= @returnvalue + 'E'
    END

 select @string, @returnvalue
```

returns

```
العربيةs    AE
```

**update** after 1st comment

```
IF(PATINDEX(N'%[أ-ي]%', RTRIM(@string ))>0)
    BEGIN
      SET @returnvalue= 'A'
    END
ELSE IF(PATINDEX(N'%[A-Za-z]%', RTRIM(@string ))>0)
    BEGIN
      SET @returnvalue= 'E'
    END

RETURN @returnvalue
```

Comment: actually i need return value arabic if one single letter belongs arabic it should decide as Arabic language that is my goal,but how to do ?

Comment: yeah i have tested your updated template, but i use same string sample it gives result as E but i need Arabic nah...single arabic char exists also .. my result should turnn over into A