# SQL Arabic Search

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, database

I have a  search program in ASP.Net C# with a SQL Server database.

Drop down list and text box to search in database but it does not find Arabic letters.

Does any one have a solution please?

Here is my code with the SQL statement

```
void GetContact(string column, string keyword)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
    com.Connection = con;
    com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Contact WHERE " + column +" LIKE '%" + keyword + "%'";
    SqlDataReader data = com.ExecuteReader();
    gvContact.DataSource = data;
    gvContact.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: What collation does your Database have?

Comment: chk this hope it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012567/how-to-check-the-string-whether-it-was-arabic-language-or-not-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: Please always use parameterized queries. This kind of string concatenations are open for SQL Injection attacks. Also use using statement to dispose your `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader`

Comment: id didnt get ur point may u explain it to me pls?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the N' prefix to indicate that you're searching for a Unicode string:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.tblArticle 
WHERE name LIKE N'%......%'
```

Comment: i just try this it does not work, maybe my syntax is wrong may u write the syntax for my CODE project!

"SELECT * FROM Contact WHERE " + column +" LIKE N'%" + keyword + "%'";

Comment: This will work *only* if the column in the database is of `NVARCHAR` type!

Comment: IT WOOOOORKs THANK UUUUUUUUUUUUUUU